# 2D Java Game Programming Animation Issue

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm working on a Swimming animation. When the player collides with the `waterTile`, the swimming animation does not play when the Player goes left (lt) and when the player goes right (rt), the up animation plays.

Here is the Render method from `Player.java`:
-EDITED-

```
if (isSwimming){
        if (up) {
            swimUp.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        } 
        if (dn){
            swimDown.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        }
        if (rt){
            swimRight.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        }
        if (lt){
            swimLeft.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        }
    }       
 if (!isSwimming){
        if(up){
            upAnimation.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        } 
        if (dn){
            downAnimation.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        }
        if (rt){
            rightAnimation.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        }
        if (lt){
            leftAnimation.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);
        } else
            idle.render(g, x, y, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE);

}
```

Also, it may be worth noting that there are no errors being displayed.

Comment: This was very hastily written so if you need any other info, edits will be made. Thank you.

Comment: You first need to find where the problem is occurring before posting code here. Are you sure that the problem is in the class posted? Where is the code that drives the animation? Wouldn't that be a more likely suspect?

Comment: Also your code is formatted poorly and is very difficult to read. "Hastily written" doesn't need to mean poorly formatted. Please consider editing your post and fixing your indentation style so that it is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (forum software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 4 spaces. Also one blank line in a row is enough. Code that is in the same block should be indented the same. Remember that you're asking volunteers to help you, and so you will need to put in extra effort to make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Inside of `if(up && isSwimming == false)` is `if (up && isSwimming == true)`? How should the inner `if` ever be reached? Also check the other if/else blocks in the method `public void render(Graphics g)`, they are all flawed.

Comment: I've tried to fix your formatting for you. Please let me know if I messed anything up.

Comment: If this is your actual code and not pseudocode, you should add brackets to your render method for all the if/else

Comment: @Compass: look at the edit history (click on the "edited x mins ago" link). You can see there that `msrd0` changed and ruined the original code.

Comment: @Tom yeah wow that's not editing or trimming ._.

Comment: I'd like to point out, that msrd0 helped fix a portion of the problem, as well as Tom. Thank you both by the way, it means a lot.

as to BitNinja, uh...I just started working on the animation a day or two ago, so that couldn't have happened. 

Anyways, thanks a lot for the help guys, it means a lot :D